# How do I set a byte value in the Windows Registry using install4j's "Set a Value in the Windows Registry" Action

Tags: install4j

I have had success using the "Set a Value in the Windows Registry" action for string values. I can't seem to get it to work for "REG_DWORD" types in the registry.  There is no way to specify the type in the install4j UI.  I have tried using an installer variable with a byte value for the registry key being set, but that got converted to a string when I check the registry.

I see the "Read" functions available in install4j work for all Windows Registry types.  Does install4j support writing a registry value of other than string types? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Set a Value in the Windows Registry" action can only set string values.

You can use the `com.install4j.api.windows.WinRegistry` API, though. If you pass a value of class `java.lang.Integer` when calling

```
WinRegistry.setValue(...)
```

a registry entry of type `REG_DWORD` is created.